# How to rename Columns via Lambda function - fasterXML

Tags: java, csv, jackson, fasterxml

Im using the [FasterXML library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) to parse my `CSV file`. The `CSV file`  has the column names in its first line. Unfortunately I need the columns to be renamed. I have a lambda function for this, where I can pass the red value from the `csv file` in and get the new value.

my code looks like this, but does not work.

```
CsvSchema csvSchema =CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();       
MappingIterator<HashMap<String,String>> it = new CsvMapper().reader(HashMap.class)
                                                    .with(csvSchema )
                                                    .readValues(new File(fileName));
            
            
            while (it.hasNext()) 
              result.add(it.next());
            
        
            System.out.println("changing the schema columns.");

            for (int i=0; i < csvSchema.size();i++) { 
                
                String name = csvSchema.column(i).getName();
                String newName = getNewName(name);
                csvSchema.builder().renameColumn(i, newName);
                
            }
            csvSchema.rebuild();
```

when i try to print out the columns later, they are still the same as in the top line of my `CSV file`.

Additionally I noticed, that `csvSchema.size()` equals `0` - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) for that. The following solution streams the input rows to the output so you don't need to load everything in memory to then write your data back with new headers. It will be much faster:

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception{

    Writer output = new StringWriter(); // use a FileWriter for your case

    CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings(); //many options here - check the documentation
    final CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(output, writerSettings);

    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();  //many options here as well
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); // indicates the first row of the input are headers

    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(new AbstractRowProcessor(){

        public void processStarted(ParsingContext context) {
            writer.writeHeaders("Column A", "Column B", "... etc");
        }

        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            writer.writeRow(row);
        }

        public void processEnded(ParsingContext context) {
            writer.close();
        }
    });

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    Reader reader = new StringReader("A,B,C\n1,2,3\n4,5,6"); // use a FileReader for your case
    parser.parse(reader); // all rows are parsed and submitted to the RowProcessor implementation of the parserSettings.

    System.out.println(output.toString());
    //nothing else to do. All resources are closed automatically in case of errors.
}
```

You can easily select the columns by using `parserSettings.selectFields("B", "A")` in case you want to reorder/eliminate columns.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. In fact we might end up in a non-constructive discussion back and forward over one product versus another.

Comment: It's not about a product vs another. Its about solving the problem at hand. If the library OP is using does not satisfy his requirements, he could try something else to get to a working solution. I can't help with Jackson, but I can with uniVocity-parsers. At least I gave OP a solution for his problem.

Comment: maybe I am voicing too much StackOverflow's general guidelines. I like your solution, I really do, but I do not think it answers the problem. I would love to see an answer to 'why columns cannot be renamed using FasterXML'. Allow me to make a little free interpretation of the OP's question. Anyway, it is all about adding context and useful information. It is clear that we don't have a pro vs cons war.